# Merging dataframes using a table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a matrix of similarity (which is built as a dataframe):

```
mat = pd.DataFrame(index = df.a.values,columns = df.a.values)
mat[:] = [[1,0.2,0.3],[0.7,1,0.6],[0,0.4,1]]
    id1     id2     id3
id1 1.0     0.2     0.3
id2 0.7     1.0     0.6
id3 0.0     0.4     1.0
```

And I would like to create another dataframe which contains the same index but with a single column containing the closest `id`:

```
    id      closest
0   id1     id3
1   id2     id1
2   id3     id2
```

The idea is to look for every row in the similarity matrix for the second highest value (the first will always be 1 on the diagonal), and retrieve the name of the corresponding column.

I know I could set the diagonal to zero, and then use something like this:

```
def closest(x):
    return np.where(x == x.max())

temp = mat.apply(lambda x: closest(x))
df['closest'] = df.index[[w[0][0] for w in temp.values]].tolist()
```

But I can't find how to filter the diagonal without reassigning it..

Note: the values in my matrix are all between 0 and 1, and the only 1 are on the diagonal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract the identity matrix, then use `DataFrame.idxmax()` to find the index of the largest value in each row.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
mat = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.7, 1, 0.6],[0, 0.4, 1]],
                   index=index, columns=index)

(mat - np.identity(3)).idxmax(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
id1    id3
id2    id1
id3    id2
dtype: object
```

Comment: Seems so simple now... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get rid of the diagonal 1s by subtracting a identity matrix of the same order. If you don't want to do any reassigning or subtracting (I don't see a reason why - probably to practice using many functions in Pandas), I would suggest something like this:

```
def closest(x):
  return mat.loc[x['id']].nlargest(2).values.tolist()[1]

def closest_label(x):
  return mat.loc[x['id']].nlargest(2).index[1]

df['closest'] = df.apply(closest, axis=1)
df['closest_label'] = df.apply(closest_label, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    id  closest closest_label
0  id1      0.3           id3
1  id2      0.7           id1
2  id3      0.4           id2
```

Comment: That is another nice answer. And despite the fact it is less efficient than Alberto's (timeit showed 500µs against 5ms for a 3-lined dataframe), it permits to do slitghly different things. Thank you!